# Using tapply to get results for a new column

Tags: r

I have a R dataFrame temp containing the following:

```
Serial N         year         current    Average 
   B              10            14          15
   C              12            13          12
   D              40            20          20
   .               .             .           .
```

I would like to add a new column based on each rows of the Average column. I tried using tapply as follow:

```
temp$new_set=tapply(temp$Average, function(x) { 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2)) - 1} )
```

But I get the following error:

```
r error in unique.default(x) unique() applies only to vectors
```

How can I apply that function on each elements of the temp$Average??

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to do `temp$Average <- (2 * pnorm(temp$Average * sqrt(2)) - 1)` ?

Comment: ^^ obviously, I meant `temp$new_set <- ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to calculate your function for each value of `Average`. If so, I do not believe you need you use `tapply` at all. Something along these lines would work:

```
temp$new_set <- (2 * pnorm(temp$Average * sqrt(2))) - 1
```

That is, you can pass directly the column `temp$Average` as the argument of your function, and obtain a result vector that can be used as your new column.

Comment: I have this when I do that: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "new_set", value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 52.

Comment: Hmmm... What are the contents of `temp$Average`? I tried to simulate yoru data and run the code, and it worked fine:

`av <- runif(52, 15, 20); temp<-data.frame(Average=av); temp$new_set <- ((2 * pnorm(temp$Average * sqrt(2))) - 1);  temp$new_set`